# Converting pandas dataframe with only one column to 1D list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [1,2,3]
i = [5,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame( { "foo" : i, "bar" : a } )
df = df.set_index("foo")
l = df.values.tolist()
# l = [[1], [2], [3]]
```

This is annoying I'w like l = [1,2,3]. Why we get a list of list? How can just get a list?

Comment: It's a dupe. Use  ravel or flatten with values

Comment: @Dark The problem is, you may not know when to call squeeze and when not to, unless you implement some checking code (checking the number of columns, for example). Otherwise, there's a function called `df.squeeze` (see my answer for info) which handles dataframes consistently.

Comment: I was in my mobile. Though learnt something new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a nice little utility function, [`df.squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) introduced in v0.20 -

```
df.squeeze()

foo
5    1
2    2
3    3
Name: bar, dtype: int64

df.squeeze().tolist()
[1, 2, 3]
```

If the dataframe has only one column, it is demoted to a series. Otherwise, nothing happens.

```
df
     bar  baz
foo          
5      1    4
2      2    5
3      3    6

df.squeeze()

     bar  baz
foo          
5      1    4
2      2    5
3      3    6
```

The advantage of this function is you can safely call `.tolist()` on its output without having to implement any additional code checks on the shape to return your desired output.

Comment: Nice; this is what I was looking for. This data frame spreads a lot on the code and checking everywere the dimentions is really annoying. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the column

```
In [4]: df["bar"].tolist()
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3]
```

`df["bar"]` creates a `Series` and it has a `.tolist()` method.

Comment: Thanks sure I know that, but I have only one column, the other one has been declared index. I was thinking this will made the dataframe 1 column and tolist method will give me a simply list.